# multi lining files in IsolatedStorage @ Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

i have created some files in the IO 
in the "car" files, i would like to put some other reference like model, color etc...
 so my question is : is it possible to have a multi-lining files in the IO
if yes how can i get them in the streamreader
// i want to storage many parameters in a file and find them again with the streamreader

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

```
            //reception des parametres de la listbox
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string parameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
            this.tbTitre.Text = parameter;
            try
            {
                //Create a new StreamReader
                StreamReader editionDevisReader = null;
                IsolatedStorageFile probyOrange = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                //Read the file from the specified location.
                editionDevisReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("devis\\"+parameter+".txt", FileMode.Open, probyOrange));
                //Read the contents of the file .
                string textFile = editionDevisReader.ReadLine();

                //Write the contents of the file to the TextBlock on the page.
                tbTitre.Text = textFile;

                while (editionDevisReader != null)
                {
                    RowDefinition rowdefinition = new RowDefinition();

                    TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
                    textblock.HorizontalAlignment = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 20); 

                }
                editionDevisReader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                //If  the file hasn't been created yet.
                tbTitre.Text = "veuillez d abord creer le fichier";
            }
```

thx a lot all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save anything (up to a point) in a file:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
        {
            sw.Write("anything really. Here it's just a string but could be a serialized object, etc.");
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then read the file with:

```
var result = string.Empty;

try
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!store.FileExists("myfile.txt"))
        {
            return result;
        }

        using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myfile.txt", FileMode.Open, store))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
            {
                string lineOfData;

                while ((lineOfData = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    result += lineOfData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (IsolatedStorageException)
{
    result = string.Empty; // may have partial data/file before error
}

return result;
```

Comment: i got that, i would like to know how to read them in the streamreader. if i create a files "car.txt" i would like to put in the files the color, the model etc... so how can i read them after ? thx a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
StreamReader.Writeline
```

and

```
StreamRead.ReadLine
```

to write and read blocks of text seperated by line feeds.

Comment: oh i see,then if i got a file like car.txt i could write smth like streamreader.writeline(2) ? where i should put the number of the line ?

Comment: Construct the line of text as a string that you want to right to a file, then it's just sw.writeline(yourstring). Repeat this while you have more cars to write. You don't need to specify the number of the line. When you write your file in this fashion, you write the entire collection out to the file using a loop when it is time to do a save. The order of the lines in cars.txt then corresponds to the order with which you did the writelines.

Comment: btw, this is very programming 101 stuff.. I applaud diving in and getting hands on, but I wondered if you've considered some training and/or a programming intro book that covers some file I/O to supplement your learning?

Comment: The thing to understand with writeline and readline, is what they do is write a line of text (like you'd see in notepad) and include linefeed at the end.. correspondingly readline reads in characters to your buffer until such time as it encounters the readline. This way you can read in one line at a time and process it into your in memory data structure readily.

Comment: hello mick, thx for your help. i learn by myself a lot (channel9, tutorial, petzold book etc) but in this case i would like to retrieve a data in the textfile. i retake my exemple with the car and his model, color etc. if i save in car.text every property from the car class, how can i make smth like carPropertyReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("typecar\\"+car+".txt", FileMode.Open, carplace)); for retrieving the color of the car ?

Comment: Those are all great resources, but just keep in mind what I'm talking about is basic programming principals which 1. apply across languages and 2. apply across specific technologies. You will find specific technologies and APIs are the topic of channel9 vids and Charles' WP7 book. As such they will consider 101 type knowledge to be assumed. They are great 201, 301, 401 resources, but you will find some focus on 101 resources in parallel will leapfrog your learning forward. With that said, let's see if we cant make a bit of progress with your immediate need.

Comment: If your immediate need is to resolve reading back in a car which you wrote out, can I suggest posting your code to that writes the car. We will then be better positioned to help you with that specific need.

Comment: ye im reading another C# book on wikibooks. on my page i got 4 textbox where i want to add in a canevas

Comment: protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            
                //reception des parametres de la listbox
                base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
                string parameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
                this.tbTitre.Text = parameter;

Comment: try
                {
                    //Create a new StreamReader
                    StreamReader editionDevisReader = null;
                    IsolatedStorageFile probyOrange = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                    //Read the file from the specified location.
                    editionDevisReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("devis\\"+parameter+".txt", FileMode.Open, probyOrange));

Comment: //Read the contents of the file .
                    string textFile = editionDevisReader.ReadLine();

                    //Write the contents of the file to the TextBlock on the page.
                    tbTitre.Text = textFile;
                    editionDevisReader.Close();
                }       catch
                {
                    //If  the file hasn't been created yet.
                    tbTitre.Text = "veuillez d abord creer le fichier";
                }
 
        }

Comment: code would be better served edited into your original post where you can apply formating to make it legible.

Comment: Regarding current reading material.. I had a quick look at the only free C# oriented 101 book I know... http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/ have a look around page 74... it's not the exhaustive intro to file handling that I expect, but it's free and accessible. We spent a reasonable amount of time on this stuff when I did comsci pre 90's, but the 101 teaching language of choice at that time was not a C dialect. Interested in some pascal or eiffel? ;)

Comment: done. and thx for the book but i a only intereted by c# and other windows phone related topics ! if i want to learn eiffel, its easy for me since i live in paris ;) (i know eiffel is a language)

Comment: im just kidding about pascal and eiffel - the book is c# - paris eh.. hmm.. nice base :)

Comment: i'm reading it right now, the introduction is really great ty

Comment: but im still stuck in my problem :(